# Using own domain model/entity on client with wcf data service (uses web api/odata/entity framework) as service reference

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, wcf-data-services, wcf-web-api

Here's my situation, I'm trying to create a WPF application that connects to my own web odata service (uses web api and entity framework). I have my own set of domain models/entities in the server side that the web api and entity framework works with. When, I add the web odata service reference in the WPF client side, it can't recognize my own domain models/entities and it looks like it creates its own set of it. Is what I'm trying to do even possible or am I just missing something?

Regards,

Raymond

Answer (score 1):

Drive-by answer (unchecked):  I remember reading that it wasn't possible at least a few weeks back. You might want to search the [Uservoice site](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions) and the [official forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=adodotnetdataservices) for current status, or wait for a better answer here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this problem is currently a feature suggestion for WCF Data Services (thanks to tne's uservoice link). The direct link to the request is https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3220086-allow-re-using-entities-from-another-dll-on-the-cl.